# Prevent bash adding single quotes

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute a command like this

```
./build -t -c cflag="-Os -march=haswell"
```

The following is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

ARGS=" -t"

MARCH=${MARCH:-haswell}
CFLAG="-Os"
CFLAG+=" -march=$MARCH"
ARGS+=" -c cflag=\"${CFLAG}\""

./build $ARGS
```

Here is `build`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

Bash always adding extra single quotes in the command:

```
+ ARGS=' -t'
+ MARCH=haswell
+ CFLAG=-Os
+ CFLAG+=' -march=haswell'
+ ARGS+=' -c cflag="-Os -march=haswell"'
+ ./build -t -c 'cflag="-Os' '-march=haswell"'
./build
-t
-c
cflag="-Os
-march=haswell"
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior in bash?

Comment: Remove `set -x`?

Comment: I need to see how the command is executed, does `set -x` affect anything?

Comment: It shows the quotes. They aren't really added anywhere.

Comment: @choroba It does affect the command, please check my update.

Comment: I don't see any single quotes in the output. Please read carefully how quoting works in shells.

Comment: The real data has _literal double quotes_ in it. The single quotes are just added to show you where the argument boundaries are as a diagnostic tool; they're not part of the real command line (which is an array of C strings, not an individual string).

Comment: This is extensively covered in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: It's not about the `set -x`. The output from build shows that it does affect the arguments.

Comment: Right. The problem is that you want your double quotes to be syntactic, but they're literal instead. That's normal and working-as-designed for very good reasons (it would be impossible to write code handling untrusted data in bash if data were silently reparsed as code).

Comment: You also have `python` involved, so this isn't exclusively a bash issue. (though the shell behavior will be)

Comment: In general, you should write your script using arrays, not strings. `args=( -t ); march=${march:-haswell}; cflags=( -Os ); cflags+=( -march="$march" ); args+=( "${cflags[@]}" ); ./build "${args[@]}"`

Comment: (note the use of lower-case variable names -- that's deliberate and per POSIX standards; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace -- to honor the convention that lowercase environment variables are reserved for application use while all-uppercase ones may reflect or modify behavior of POSIX-defined tools, one needs to use lowercase names for regular shell variables, because setting an uppercase shell variable name will overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: ...now, there _are_ cases where values are passed as strings rather than arrays for either compatibility or interface-limitation reasons -- f/e, environment variables are just individual C strings and cannot be arrays. In those cases, the answers on the linked duplicates are appropriate.

Comment: You code generates `./build -t -Os -march=haswell` not `./build -t -c cflag="-Os -march=haswell"`. The thing that really bugs me is the double quote in `cflag=`.

Comment: @DreamLinuxer, `args+=( cflag="${cflags[*]}" )` if that's what you want then. Mind, that has some serious caveats of its own; if I knew that the content of `cflag=` was going to be parsed by the same shell, I would use `printf '%q ' "${cflags[@]}"` to generate the string to use there. However, in practice it's likely that it _won't in fact_ be parsed by bash (even if a shell is invoked it's likely to be `/bin/sh`), so going the route that would be the Right Thing for consumption by bash likely the wrong thing in the real-world scenario.

Comment: @DreamLinuxer, ...note that the double quote being literal _is the whole problem_. If it were correctly syntactic, you would get `'cflag=-Os -march=haswell'` emitted by `set -x` (in some versions of bash; the details are version-defined -- think of `set -x` like using Python's `repr()` to print results, where a single string can be written out several possible ways)

Comment: ...and just to be clear, `'cflag=-Os -march=haswell'` and `cflag="-Os -march=haswell"` and `cflag=-Os\ -march=haswell` (and, for that matter, `cflag=-Os" "-march=haswell`) are different ways of representing _the exact same string_ in bash; which one of those representations `set -x` happens to use is immaterial.

Comment: Now it becomes `./build -t 'cflag=-Os -march=haswell'`, the double quote is missing. The output from build becomes `['./build', '-t', 'cflag=-Os -march=haswell']`, but I need it to be `['./build', '-t', 'cflag="-Os -march=haswell"']`.

Comment: If you would run `./build -t cflag="-Os -march=haswell"` at a shell, **the double quotes are syntactic, not literal**. They're gone before `python` is started. See what I said above about there being lots of different ways to write the same string.

Comment: Try it -- check your `sys.argv` between both `./build -t cflag="-Os -march=haswell"` and `./build -t 'cflag=-Os -march=haswell'`; you'll see it's identical.

Comment: I see, so they will disappear no matter how I pass the arguments. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240878/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-dreamlinuxer).

Comment: Since you are using bash, you want to use a shell array for this -- use `ARGS=("-t")` to initially set the array to a single value, then `ARGS+=("-c" "cflag=$CFLAG")` to add two more args to it, then `./build "${args[@]}"` to call build with those arguments (and without resplitting them, so the space in cflag will remain untouched.)